# how to handle relationships in laravel where the foreign key field is not required and may sometimes be left out

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

Please note that I'm using Mysql where nulls arent allowed in foreign key fields.

Say there is a table, Users, with the fields name, mypic_id, familypic_id, carpic_id and housepic_id.

There is also a table used to for images, Pics,  with the fields id, title, filename and path.

The fields mypic_id, familypic_id, carpic_id and housepic_id may be added at a later date or not at all for each user.

each of the *pic_id fields are related to a Pics record via hasOne (one-one) in the User model

When I add/update a record from the Users table, I get the following error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ...

How can I overcome this issue using Eloquent / Laravel 4?

Comment: I don't think you can have a foreign key constraint in a field that is not required when creating a new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are incorrect that you can't have NULL values in MySQL foreign key fields.  I am using MySQL with numerous foreign key fields that regularly store null values.  I would suggest you look at the definition of your foreign id field and see whether you have set it to NOT NULL.  If you change it to DEFAULT NULL instead you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent relations don't require foreign key constraints on the db side, so you can simply remove those constraints and it will work.

Mind though that you have to worry about updating/removing entries in related tables then, as MySQL will have no idea about it and you won't be able to setup ON UPDATE, ON DELETE actions.

Comment: that can work, but unfortunately not acceptable for this project, appreciate the effort though

Comment: So there is some inconsistency: you said that those relations may be set later or not at all, so how could you do that with foreign key constraints?

Comment: doesn't laravel/eloquent control the relationships in the database anyway

Comment: Nope, it does not do any checks on constraints

Answer (score 0):

You need to plan ahead, if you are adding the other pics in the future it would be better to build that relationship now.

Have a 1 - Many relationship with pics and have pictureType field on your pics table. You can then add scopes to your pictures class and get the exact you need.

**DB Structure**

users

id, name, ....

pics

id, users_id, picData, type (enum or link to another table), ...

**Files**

Your Users.php would have the following relationship

```
public function pics()
{
    return $this->hasMany('pics',users_id);
}
```

In your Pics.php you could than add a relationship and scope such as

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Users');
}

public function scopeType($query,$type)
{
    return $query->where('type', '=', $type);
}
```

this would allow you to get any pics you have now or any future pics by calling

```
User::find(1)->pics()->type('myPic')->get();
```